# How to change value in previous TD via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a button when clicked on runs a function and I want the value in the previous TD to change to yes from no.

HTML:

```
<tr class="odd">
  <td class="">13.00</td>
  <td class="">DDR</td>
  <td class="">No</td>
  <td class="">
    <div class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="javascript:paid(4);return false" href="#" "="" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
       <span class="ui-button-text">Paid</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So when the user clicks on "Paid" this is called.. Javascript:

```
function paid(iD) {       
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        url: "Paid",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{ id:" + iD +"}",
        success: function (id) {
            //Here change value of previous TD to yes;

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
        }
    });
};
```

Is there a way I can access the html of the previous td and change the value of it?

O and also make the button disappear?

Comment: Is it always going to be the last td?

Comment: no there will be several rows with the button in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way that will work. But with these kind of things you need to be careful about changing your html after:

```
$("span.ui-button-text").click(function(){
    var td = $(this).closest("td").prev();
    //do ajax here
});
```

this will allow you to store the correct `td` cell and then you can reference that inside your success callback. For example:

```
td.html("Yes");
```

Comment: yeah, what's your point? you can still access the same way. If you not already got the ID then you do not ask that.

Comment: I would recommend tagging the div with the ID value so you can access if more freely. For example, you could set a data attribute with the id using `data-paidid="4"` and then access this with javascript in the `click` event with `var id = $(this).data("paidid");`

Comment: Old msg but to ans your question for future readers: insert `id` returned by ajax: `td.html(id);`. You would put that where musefan has indicated: `//do ajax here`

Answer (score 1):

The key here is preserving a reference to the outer `this` (the clicked button). Once you enter the success callback, the context is lost, because it's nan asynchronous operation.

We can capture the outer `this`, though, with an immediately-executed function, passing it in as an argument reference.

```
    success: (function(button) { return function (id) {
        $(button).closest('td').prev('td').text('yes');
    }; })(this)
```

Comment: The OP will want to know where `that` came from.

Comment: Renamed to `button` to make it more indicative.

Comment: I created also one [little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BxxL/), this closure is really good and functional solution.

Answer (score 0):

Work around

add an ID to the TR element

```
<tr id="tr1" class=".odd">
```

AND

```
<div class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="javascript:paid(4,"tr1");return false" href="#" "="" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

and modify your paid function as

```
paid(id, rowId);
```

TD as

```
<td class="yn">No</td>
```

and success handler

```
success: function (id) {
$("#"+rowId+" .yn").html("Yes");
}
```

==============================================
OLD :
Simple way is give your yes/no TD a class
say yn

so your TD looks like

```
<td class="yn">No</td>
```

and implement your success handler as

```
success: function (id) {
$(".odd .yn").html("Yes");
},
```

Comment: but then all the tds with yes will change i only want the previous one now all to change

Comment: can you bind this click event by jQuery?
That way we can get the reference of the TR which fired that event?

OR you can send ID of your row as a parameter to paid function. So that you can do it like $("#"+rowID+" .yn").html("Yes");

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<td class="" id="paid">No</td>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("paid").innerHTML = "Yes";
```

Comment: but there will be several rows with yes, i only want previous td to change not all of them

Comment: ids are unique so you can have your ids be numbers and then use an increment variable in javascript to access the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be using the context property of $.ajax(..) to save a reference to the previous TD which you want modified.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
        ...
        context: prevTD, // specify the previous TD as context
        ...
        success: function (data) {
            // 'this' refers to the passed in context
            // so you can do 
            this.text('Yes');
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
        }
    });
```

For getting the previous TD from where you are calling, you can use:

```
yourPaidButton.parents('TD').first().prev()
```